# Character's Underlying Mesh is showing through top mesh of Jeans

Tags: mesh, armature

I downloaded a character model/rig and have been experiencing problems with the mesh of the jeans. When the character is facing forward, the jeans look fine. Once you rotate the character or move the legs, the underlying body mesh shows through the jeans. How can I fix this?

Rig facing forward:
[image]

[image]

Rig slightly rotated on Z axis:
[image]
As you can see the skin mesh is showing from underneath the jeans mesh. What could be going wrong here and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete this part of your mesh. If you prefer a non-destructive way you could give your object a *Mask* modifier:

- In *Edit* mode, select the part you want to make invisible, assign it to a group.
- Back in *Object* mode, give your object a *Mask* modifier, in the *Vertex Group* field, choose the group you've created, click on the arrow on the right to invert the masking effect.

[image]

Comment: The Mask modifier worked, thank you so much!!